# Where do sagas live in a microservice architecture?

Tags: microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

Assume you have two microservices (a customer service and an account service). Both services are deployed as a Spring Boot applications running in separate Docker containers. Each time a customer is created by the customer service, an CustomerCreatedEvent is fired to Axon Server. In response to this event, the account service should create a corresponding account keeping track of the customer's balance.

I don't wish to "listen" to CustomerCreatedEvents in the account service avoiding dependencies to the customer service. Instead I want to use sagas to control the orchestration of this "flow".

The question I have is fairly simple. Where should the saga handlers be packaged and deployed?

- I suppose the saga logic should never be a part of one of both microservices since this introduces dependencies which is what I want to avoid.
- I guess the saga logic should be deployed as a stand-alone (e.g. Spring Boot) application in its own container? What will happen if the "saga container" becomes unavailable? I expect it to pick-up everything where it left as soon as it becomes available again. Is it possible to run multiple instances of this "saga container" simultaneously for scalability, or should there only be one instance running?
- Or is there another approach better suited to deploy the "saga logic"?

Most of the examples I found online are all-in-one examples. Feel free to point me to other resources/posts answering this question.

Thank you for reading and replying to my post.

**###EDIT 01 (after response by Carmine Ingaldi)###**

One possible solution is indeed choreography-based sagas where each µSVC is responsible for handling its own part of the story as described by Carmine. This introduces "awareness" (or code dependencies if you like) to event/command types defined in other services (and boundary contexts), something I'd like to avoid. This is where **orchestration-based sagas** come into play (together with some other undocumented advantages). Off course, special care should be taken not to include any or as little as possible business logic in the saga handler component.

[image]

As depicted above, the *Customer-Account-Saga* is now in control of orchestrating all commands to be emitted for correspoding event being handled.

In my initial question I was confused where this orchestration logic should be developed/deployed? I assume in this case a dedicated application is deployed as a separate container while in the other (equally valid) approach, the saga logic is part of the µSVC itself.

Other approaches than either choreography or orchestration based sages are off course appreciated in the discussion.

**###END OF EDIT 01###**

Comment: <<I don't wish to "listen" to CustomerCreatedEvents in the account service avoiding dependencies to the customer service>> that's exactly why we use event driven architectures: to let events mediate between services. Sagas have a different purpose: in your case a saga would be needed if the account creation should come after make sure an account can be created, according to some rules (fraud check etc)

Comment: That's indeed exactly why sagas are used, to introduce transaction-like behaviour among different microservices. Event mediation is not the only reason though to use event driven architectures, but that's not the point of the question. ;-)

Comment: I agree, but this means that a saga is only needed when a DISTRIBUTED transaction state is shared among different services and needs to be updated according to BASE  constraints. In this case, a change occurred in some downstream service, could affect the upstream service (eg, an error occurred and both need to completely reset the transaction status) while in your example this part is missing. It's just a producer/consumer, upstream/downstream dynamics where the point of contact between service boundaries is represented from the event contract

Answer (score 1):

what you're describing is not a saga it is a workflow. Sagas handle the long running transaction part but the context and understanding of the meaning is kept within the participating services and their cooperation is "choreographed"

Workflows externalize some of the logic and it owns logic. The workflow "orchestrate" the interactions (a lot of times leads to more passive services) it is easy to tip the scale and amass a lot of service logic in the workflow but it can still be helpful if the orchestration logic is the volatile logic that changes a lot

Comment: Indeed, one should see it as workflows. This makes it very interesting and beneficial from business modelling point of view (increasing readability for non technical members of the project team and easy updatable due to changes) to design/define those "workflow" in a BPMN modelling tool and execute the "sagas" from within a BPM engine.

Answer (score 1):

After introducing the topic through my comments, let's see first how to design and structure a saga.

Sagas come from *policies* which are rules that are checked when a certain condition occurs. These rules can also be checked outside the system (from human actors or 3rd party systems), leading to **long running transactions**, which in turn constrain us to design the entire workflow as asynchronous.

So let's add some spice to your example. A policy can be

> **Whenever** an user has been created
>
> **Then** Fraud team performs fraud checks on the customer

So now we have two scenario

> Scenario 1: happy path
>
> Event: Fraud Check Passed -> Command: Create Account
> Event: Account Created -> Command: Notify User Account Creation

> Scenario 2: Fraudulent Customer
>
> Event: Fraud Check Rejected -> Command: Delete User
> Event: User Deleted -> Command: Notify User Removal

As you can see, the status of Accounts service depends on the outcome of an action performed outside (there can be a "fraud check microservice") and, in turn, the status of Usera service depends on the outcome of the account creation on the Accounta service. this means that every service performs a step of the complex transaction and each one has the responsibility to inform the othera to go ahead in the process or roll it back to the last valid state (in a non-atomic fashion). This means that every service should implement its part of the saga and hold the saga state, so

> I guess the saga logic should be deployed as a stand-alone (e.g. Spring Boot) application in its own container?

Answer: no

So in the most complex cases, the architecture should look like that

[image]

Where every service Saga will listen for events and emit commands towards an associated aggregate. Turns out that every service is a participant in a complex process, that's why we call this pattern as "coreography"

So now we have to rephrase the second question

> What will happen if the "saga container" becomes unavailable?

Even though there is no saga container, the process can be blocked due to unavailability of the involved parts, loss of messages or because the whole thing it's just taking too long. In this case the proper countermeasure is to set up **Deadlines** that will be check if the saga (or any corresponding local part of the process) doesn't get into some specific state within a certain time. In this case the process can be considered failed and take corresponding actions

So, following your example, a dedline can be set up if the fraud check doesn't get completed in a week, so we consider the customer as rejected and we will take corresponing actions

**PS:**
Notice that here there is no depedency between services: even though the definition of *dependency* is kinda blurred in the software engineering world, we can say that a service A depends on B if some change in B leads to some change in A. Here the services can change in a totally independent way as long as they don't change the event content, but this aspect is more related with broader concept of event driven architectures than with Sagas, which are just one of the behavioural patterns that you can find in a EDA

Comment: I agree with your explanation and the described approach. I have edited my question a bit to further clarify my question. I initially did not mention I intended to use orchestration-based sagas instead of choreography-based sagas, which is off course my mistake :-)